# Ordenar consulta sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

quisiera saber como puedo hacer que el registro "todos" se muestre siempre al final del resultado de la consulta sql, estoy utilizando para las consultas sql developer

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes crear una columna, la cual sea el orden principal, y utilizando CASE, puedes establecerla con un uno cuando la columna de nombre sea todos, y asignarle un 0 a los demás registros, entonces puedes ordenar por el orden principal, y luego ordenar por todos los demás criterios que quieras.

```
SELECT ID_CANAL, NOMBRE, CASE WHEN NOMBRE = 'Todos' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ORDEN_PRINCIPAL FROM [Tabla] ORDER BY ORDEN_PRINCIPAL, ID_CANAL
```

Comment: Tambien podría ponerlo directo en el Order By con lo siguiente:  ORDER BY (CASE WHEN NOMBRE = 'Todos' THEN -1 ELSE ID_CANAL END) ASC

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda, me sirvió totalmente! te pasaste